# What should minRCU and minWCU should be set for dynamodb in case of spikes only for few times?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

We have a service built in AWS which only gets traffic for few minutes in entire day and then there is no traffic at all. During the burst, say, we get traffic at 200 TPS otherwise, traffic is almost zero during the entire day. This dynamodb has auto scaling enabled.

The thing I wanted to know is how should we set minWCU and minWCU for it. Should it be determined by the most traffic we expected to traffic or the minimum traffic we receive? If I do minimum traffic, say 10, and set utilization as 50%, then I see that some events gets throttled since autoscaling takes time to increase capacity units. But setting the min capacity units according to most traffic that we receive increases the cost of dynamodb, in which case we are incurring cost even when we are not using the dynamodb at all. So, are there any best practices regarding this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your situation, you might be better going with [on-demand](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.ReadWriteCapacityMode.html#HowItWorks.OnDemand) mode.

> DynamoDB on-demand offers pay-per-request pricing for read and write requests so that you pay only for what you use.

This frees you from managing RCUs, WCUs, and autoscaling. There would be no need for pro-active scaling

Be sure to review the [considerations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/switching.capacitymode.html) before making that change

Comment: I disagree with this! If we switch to on-demand mode, then there are chances of throttling as the previous peak will be less in OPs case, how can dynamoDB handle that ?

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have consistent traffic then its better to set to close to what the burst is, as it takes 5 minutes before scaling up you might find your credits depleted before it scales.